# Warning: Array to string conversion base64_encode

Tags: php

When I do this `$payload2 =  base64_encode($payload);` I will get message "Expected type : string" so I change to `$payload2 =  base64_encode((string)$payload);` but I will get the "Warning: Array to string conversion" error. How to solve this error?

```
$header = array(
            "alg" => "HS256",
            "typ" => "JWT", 
            );
$header2 =  base64_encode((string)$header);
```

---

Solution of using json_encode:

```
$header =json_encode(['typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => 'HS256']);
$base64UrlHeader = str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($header));
```

Comment: Array is not mutable to string and base64_encode needs string. Create string. Encode string. Use for example `implode()`.

Comment: Instead of `implode()`, it will be better to `json_encode` the array to get the string so that when you're decoding the base64 encoded string, you can easily get back the headers with `json_decode`

Comment: @Haridarshan can you help me to check if my code of using json_encode is correct?

Comment: yes... it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `implode()`

```
$header = array(
            "alg" => "HS256",
            "typ" => "JWT", 
            );
$header2 = implode("",$header);
$header3 =  base64_encode($header2);
```